# How to set the window title after startup of an RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I am programming an e4 RCP application and would like to set it's window title once it has started. However I could not find any way to realise that.

Reason is, I would like to add some explicit info about the running program so the user can differ between multiple launches.

Any hints on that?

Comment: Right now I am doing a getShell().setText() in one of the Parts I have created. But I want a more common solution since I don't know when the part is actually opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In e4 you can set the main window title by calling the `setLabel` method of the `MWindow` for the main window. Use the `EModelService` to find the main window.

A suitable place to do this might be in an 'application startup complete' event in your RCP LifeCycle class

```lava
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE) Event event, 
                               EModelService modelService, MApplication application)
{
  MWindow window = (MWindow)modelService.find("top window id", application);

  window.setLabel("new window title");
}
```

Note: `Event` is `org.osgi.service.event.Event`